# Logic app loop through all elements on the array and add it to the body/description

Tags: arrays, loops, jira, element, azure-logic-apps

Actually I don't know if this will work. But I have long array with a lot of elements, I need to display all element in order on the body/description of Jira ticket without writing it manually (example: `outputs('Compose')?[0] outputs('Compose')?[1] outputs('Compose')?[2]` ). Is there anyway to do it using loop? or any other method?

**Note: I don't want it to be as paragraph I need it the same as the array listed.**

**Example array:**

`[ 'first element', 'second element', 'third element', ]`

**printed/displayed format:**

first element

second element

third element

---

I tried using loop but don't understand it.

please consider that I'm new to the Logic App or any other technologies with the same idea

Comment: So just to be clear, you want to write the contents of the array down the page separated by a new line? As simple as that?

Comment: Yes that what I was looking for, I tried the join solution that someone suggest and it works! thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are ways which we can perform data operations such as:

- Line by line
- Spaces

**Option 1: Line by line**

Firstly, I have initialized a variable as below:

[image]

Then used Join (Data Operations) as below:

[image]

(here I just clicked Enter in Join with )

Output:

[image]

[image]

Code view:

```
{
    "definition": {
        "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
        "actions": {
            "Initialize_variable": {
                "inputs": {
                    "variables": [
                        {
                            "name": "emo",
                            "type": "array",
                            "value": [
                                "rithwik",
                                "bojja",
                                "chotu"
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "runAfter": {},
                "type": "InitializeVariable"
            },
            "Join": {
                "inputs": {
                    "from": "@variables('emo')",
                    "joinWith": "\n"
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "Initialize_variable": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "Join"
            }
        },
        "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
        "outputs": {},
        "parameters": {},
        "triggers": {
            "manual": {
                "inputs": {
                    "schema": {}
                },
                "kind": "Http",
                "type": "Request"
            }
        }
    },
    "parameters": {}
}
```

So now you can use the output of Join`(body('Join')`

**Option 2: Spaces**

If you keep space in Join you will get ouput as below:

[image]

Output:

[image]

Code view:

```
{
    "definition": {
        "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
        "actions": {
            "Initialize_variable": {
                "inputs": {
                    "variables": [
                        {
                            "name": "emo",
                            "type": "array",
                            "value": [
                                "rithwik",
                                "bojja",
                                "chotu"
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "runAfter": {},
                "type": "InitializeVariable"
            },
            "Join": {
                "inputs": {
                    "from": "@variables('emo')",
                    "joinWith": " "
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "Initialize_variable": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "Join"
            }
        },
        "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
        "outputs": {},
        "parameters": {},
        "triggers": {
            "manual": {
                "inputs": {
                    "schema": {}
                },
                "kind": "Http",
                "type": "Request"
            }
        }
    },
    "parameters": {}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume that what you end up putting together needs to be separated by a html line break (i.e. `<br>`) but if this not the case then you can make it whatever you want.

I've just tried to mimic what you provided with this basic flow ...

[image: Flow]

You can see the first step is a compose for your array and the second step is initialising a string variable using the `join` expression.  This concatenates all strings within the array together separated by the HTML line break.

```
join(outputs('Compose'), '<br>')
```

**Result**

[image: Result]

Comment: Hi thanks for response I understand your idea I tried it but the result is not what I am looking for but the same idea. Thank you!